# Why are MO accounts not listed among other SE accounts?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, stackexchange

When I go look at my [accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/267077/martin?tab=accounts) in SE network, mathoverflow is not listed there. (You can get to the list of accounts, for example, from your profile page. Other SE accounts are listed on profile page.)

I have checked profile pages of a few other users and noticed the same thing - math.SE is listed as one of the accounts, MO is not.

Comment: I think that you may have to link it to the main account. I actually prefer it this way.

Comment: To me it seems synced as the other accounts appear on the MO profile page. But not the other way round.

Comment: But not the MO account itself, which seems to have dropped off *all* profile pages at the same time. (I seem to remember it still being there on all pages a short while ago. Maybe a glitch?)

Comment: It seems that some users have mathoverflow listed among their accounts, see [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/510579/alex-b?tab=accounts).

Comment: But even on Alex B's profile (the user Martin Sleziak links to) it's not perfect: Alex has certainly posted more on MO than 0 questions and 1 answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now that we've done the import, we'll need to refresh our global network cache of users and posts from all sites.  The fun part is this is a *huge* job, so we have to take portions of the API offline for a bit to do it...which means we don't want to do it twice.

Today we'll be checking that everything is ready for a backfill and we don't need to do anything else that would just cause us to do another one.  Once we're pretty confident we've gotten everything adjusted, we'll run that backfill and your network accounts will be correct on SE.com and elsewhere.

Comment: Don't you think this question better be placed on the main meta site as it's about the network profile?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not really. It only affects MO, and we monitor child metas as well (clearly :)), so this is getting fixed either way and the question is on the meta site where it's most likely to help the community it affects.