# Math Overflow not available as a chat parent user

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I was configuring the Teacher's Lounge ping for MO when I realized that currently, the option to change chat parent user to MO is not available. Could this be added?

Also, superpings don't seem to work:

[image]

Comment: working on that already

Comment: @balpha great, thanks :)

Comment: Heads up, this is a fairly big thing so it may take a bit. See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/58/why-are-mo-accounts-not-listed-among-other-se-accounts, which is what's behind this.

Comment: @balpha yeah, I later was reading up on the meta and that looked like the root cause. A note: I already managed to associate the S.Carnahan chat account as he didn't have an original SE chat account.