# People without math.SE profile cannot join chat?

Tags: bug, chat

There appears to be some problem with people who are not members at math.SE conencting to at least one chatroom (the recently created "Homotopy Theory" chat room). That is, people with MO profiles are being asked to "log in" when they click on that link.  Is this what should be happening? Will this change any time soon?

Thanks!
-Jon

Comment: It's not about MSE profile, it's a global SE profile. I think they are working on that...

Comment: This http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/72/math-overflow-not-available-as-a-chat-parent-user might be relaated and what @AsafKaragila had in mind.

Comment: We're working on it, it [is a network thing](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/58/why-are-mo-accounts-not-listed-among-other-se-accounts) that I hope we can have resolved quite soon, but I don't have a definite ETA (yet) - I will update various questions here when I do. Please 'pardon the dust' for just a bit longer - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @quid: Are you a made out of wood?

Comment: In the meantime, ping me if anyone needs a chat profile, I was already able to create on for an MO mod a while ago.

Comment: @Manishearth thanks! I think http://mathoverflow.net/users/16682/jim-stasheff was trying to join the chat room.

Comment: @JonBeardsley Ah, he has a chat profile but no chat rep. I can give him explicit access to a room, which room do you need?

Comment: he just wanted access to the homotopy theory chat.

Comment: thanks so much for your help.  I'm not minding the "dust" just wanted to see if I could help Jim out

Comment: @JonBeardsley Done, he should be able to talk there now

Comment: Note that everyone still has to log in for chat

Comment: Jon, sent you email