# The bit about parent user and the netwok not realizing I am on MO. Or network

Tags: bug

Alright, I am going to ask this about myself, then I will go read the other one about MO not being available as a chat parent. That turned out to be [Math Overflow not available as a chat parent user](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/72/math-overflow-not-available-as-a-chat-parent-user)

Indeed, If I just go to my profile here, I get

[image]

but then if I go to my "network profile" it is all MSE and shows no hint of MO at all

[image]

Anyway, most everything works alright. If it is going to take a few weeks to get everybody's parent accounts straightened out, I just won't create any more chat rooms until then.

Comment: See [the answer](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/89/9479) to [Why are MO accounts not listed among other SE accounts?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/58/why-are-mo-accounts-not-listed-among-other-se-accounts): *Once we're pretty confident we've gotten everything adjusted, we'll run that backfill and your network accounts will be correct on SE.com and elsewhere.*

Comment: @AméricoTavares, thanks, that does seem to be about this issue.