# How to merge old mathoverflow account?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I know that this question has been asked and answered here: [How can I log in into my old mathoverflow account?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account) I have e-mailed the stackoverflow admins twice, but nothing has happened for 48h now.  Since I have merely 1 reputation I can not comment on anything or make myself noticable in other ways than asking this question.  How should I proceed to get my accounts merged?
Here's my old account: https://mathoverflow.net/users/5495/thomas-kahle
Of course this question can be deleted...

Comment: OK, now this does not appear on the homeapge anymore already.  Has this question been deleted?

Comment: Still visible. I suspect the answer to the 48 hour thing is here: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/58/why-are-mo-accounts-not-listed-among-other-se-accounts  but there seemed to be one, more specific, about merging individual accounts. Not sure. You might just go back through all Meta questions, so far, on the right, it says there are two uses of the tag user-accounts, for example.

Comment: Some of the others tagged support might be closer.

Comment: I understand that there are still some problems to resolve like people wanting their SO network profiles connected to the MO account or not.  However, I don't understand why merging accounts stopped (or my mails didn't reach them).  In one of the threads it says they had 'support people in different time zones' which indicates that 24h should be a good upper bound for this to be processed.

Comment: ,see if posting an "answer" here helps: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account?lq=1  There are some 35 successes, each deleted by Anton after resolution, most seem to be on June 25 and 26. This is a weekend now, it might matter.

Comment: I see, that's the first one you mention...