# How do I login to my old MathOverflow account?

Tags: support, status-completed, login

I realise that this question has been asked in various forms already, but I still have a problem.

I have an old MathOverflow account

https://mathoverflow.net/users/6827/konstantin-ardakov

and a new one, created in the last week

https://mathoverflow.net/users/5791/konstantin-ardakov

I am able to login to the second, but not the first one. I believe I've emailed the Stack Exchange team already a couple of days ago, but got no reply.

What should I do to regain access to the first account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged your accounts, so you should be good to go.

Thank you for your patience, and I apologize for the delay in getting this sorted out.

Comment: have you seen this one? http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/292/how-to-merge-old-mathoverflow-account  I think it is the same problem...

Comment: Strange how it keeps clipping off the initial salutation. Maybe just when the system is sure there is only one person being addressed?

Comment: Anna: thanks, seems to be sorted now.

Will: I did see it. But having only 11 rep points I couldn't comment under the question, so I thought I might as well ask again...

Comment: @KonstantinArdakov New questions are easier for us to notice, so it's all good.